# Elegir que registros presentar en una consulta Mysql

Tags: mysql

amigos... ya estamos con averías...

Una Consulta MySql facilita..

```
SELECT * FROM `controltrabajadores` WHERE Fecha='2021-06-26' Order BY Operario ASC, id ASC
```

me devuelve correctamente dos registros por trabajador.

```
Trabajador 1:
id=1.... Nombre............Fecha........
id=2.....Nombre............Fecha........

Trabajador 2:
id=3.... Nombre............Fecha........
id=4.....Nombre............Fecha........
```

Lo que necesito es que solo me muestre el primer registro de Cada Trabajador....

```
id=1.... Nombre............Fecha........
id=3.... Nombre............Fecha........
```

No vale por numeros impares, puede cambiar esa situación,

Lo mismo estoy preguntando una Gilipollez, pero no lo veo....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tampoco es una consulta tan evidente:

```
SELECT * FROM controltrabajadores
    WHERE id IN (
        SELECT MIN(id)
          FROM controltrabajadores
          WHERE Fecha='2021-06-26'
          AND NOT MOD(id,2)
          GROUP BY Operario
    )
    ORDER BY Operario ASC, id ASC;
```

Suponiendo que `id` es un autonumérico y los registros los insertas en orden, la idea es agrupar por trabajador, quedándote con el que tenga el `id` no impar más bajo, y después seleccionas únicamente los registros con esos `id`.

Comment: Perfecto, tambien puedo elegir entre pares e impares enel MOD...